# Attempting to use Full Calendar click event display to show pop up window with additional event information

Tags: r, events, shiny, fullcalendar

I have a Fullcalendar in shiny that is getting "events" from respective columns of a filtered data frame. Ideally, I would like for additional data to be displayed (from corresponding rows / different columns of the data frame) when one of the events is clicked on. I have attached code for reference:

```
# #Calendar Billing History (Billed)
 calendar <- data.frame(Account_Num,Account_Num_Spec,Account_Name,Billing_Num,Date,Tran_Type,Transaction_Amt2,CAL_DATE,color,CAL_DATE2)
 calendar_subset <- reactive({
 c4 <- calendar

return(c4)
})

# CALENDAR
LOL1 <- reactive({
data1 <- calendar_subset()
data1$CAL_DATE2 <- format(as.Date(data1$CAL_DATE2, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
hope1 <- c(as.character(data1$Billing_Num))
hope2 <- c(data1$CAL_DATE2)
hope3 <- c(as.character(data1$color))
hope4 <- c(data1$Transaction_Amt2)
fullcalendar(events = data.frame(
  #title = c("ex1","ex2","ex3"),
  #start = c("2020-01-15","2020-02-14","2019-12-07"), #Sys.Date() + 0:1,
  #color = c("red","green","red"))) #"red", "orange")
  title = c(hope1),
  start = c(hope2), #Sys.Date() + 0:1,
  #end = c(hope2),
  color = c(hope3),
  description = c(hope4)))
}) 

output$test <- renderFullcalendar({LOL1()})
```

Comment: If you have additional data these can be added to your event data as additional properties. Then you can use fullCalendar's `eventRender` callback to manipulate the HTML of each event to include the extra properties, however you wish to display them.

Comment: The additional data is in the same dataframe just in different columns (and corresponding rows). How would this up based on the fullCalendar function above?

Comment: I have no idea about anything in R or dataframes, sorry. But in terms of the fullCalendar object, you would add additional properties just the same way you are adding `title`, `start`, `color` and `description` right now, I think.